# Angular What is the best practice to open another dialog after closing another one?

Tags: angular, material-ui

Currently i got some feedbacks that I should not do this as my colleagues said that was a nested subscription, and should avoid using this.
Just wanna open a simple message dialog after closing the first one and when the first one returns a true value. Is there any way better than this one?

```
weatherProtectDialog.afterClosed()
    .subscribe((result) => {
      if (result) {
        this.dialog.open(SimpleDialogComponent, {
          data: {
            title: 'title',
            message: 'message',
          },
        });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RxJS operators to avoid nested subscriptions.

```
weatherProtectDialog.afterClosed()
.pipe(
    filter(res => res),
    tap(() => this.dialog.open(SimpleDialogComponent, {
        data: {
          title: 'title',
          message: 'message',
        },
    }))
).subscribe()
```

Filter operator: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/filter

Tap operator: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap

Another solution could be to transform this observable into a promise and work with async/await to avoid nesting, however since you are using Angular I recommend you to use RxJS